# Como contestar automáticamente una llamada en android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Quiero que el teléfono conteste automáticamente la llamada cuando esta sea detectada. Según he visto ya tengo hecho lo más difícil, pues mi app ya detecta cuando una llamada está entrando y cuando el teléfono está IDL, pero aún así no he podido conseguir que conteste. Estoy utilizando el telephonyManager, ya he revisado todas las preguntas hechas en stackOverflow en inglés y no he podido. Aquí les dejo mi código

Clase que detecta el estado del teléfono

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TelephonyMethods.AnswerRinginCall(telephonyManager);//método que debe hacer al teléfono contestar

            }
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Received!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "IDL!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Clase del método answerIncomingCall

```
public class TelephonyMethods {

    public static void AnswerRinginCall(final TelephonyManager manager){
        manager.answerRingingCall();
    }


}
```

Método en la clase TelephonyManager

```
@SystemApi
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)
    public void answerRingingCall() {
        try {
            ITelephony telephony = getITelephony();
            if (telephony != null)
                telephony.answerRingingCall();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error calling ITelephony#answerRingingCall", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y exactamente ¿qué problema te da? ¿alguna excepción, o simplemente no funciona? ¿Has puesto algunos logs para ver qué métodos son llamados?

Comment: simplemente no funciona, no tengo ni idea :(